# How do I get the filename and job numer of an "at" job

Tags: php, at

We have a script (generator) that is creating a series of `at` jobs. The `at` jobs fire another PHP script. The generator script loops through and does something like this:

```
exec('/usr/bin/at 5:00 May 11, 2015 -f ' . $filename);
```

$filename looks something like this:

```
php /some-location/some-script.php arg1 arg2 arg3
```

It's working awesome, we love it. What I'm trying to figure out is how to grab the job id and the file name in `/var/spool/at/filename` from the generator script as it runs so I can store it in case we need to alter/cancel after they been scheduled.

Does anyone have any idea how I can grab that info from the `exec()` that's creating the `at` Job?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation on PHP [exec()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

> If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command.

Does your version of `at` declare the job number?

```
$ echo /bin/true | at now + 1hour
job 1 at Fri Apr 24 12:00:00 2015
```

If so, you might then use [explode()](https://php.net/explode) with a space delimiter to get the job number.

```
<?php
    // Remember to redirect stderr to stdout with "2>&1"
    $command = "echo /bin/true | at now + 1hour 2>&1";

    $at_message = explode(" ", exec($command, $output, $return_value));
    $job_number = $at_message[1];
    echo $job_number;
?>
```

Comment: it does not use a job number - i really need the filename in var/spool/at. thanks for the info on exec though, i'm sure that'll come in useful